# JSON parsing C# get specific data

Tags: c#, json

Here is the JSON that needed to be proper parsed:

https://docs.acrcloud.com/metadata

i am trying to get the:

title of the song,
album name,
artists.

I tried like this:

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);            
 Console.WriteLine("Name: " + o["metadata"]["music"]);
```

and it works but i am getting all the data in "music" i just need to extract the specific data.

Comment: Then take your "specific data" instead!

Comment: i don't know how @cubrr check the JSON it is little bit complicated

Comment: Well, you've already got "music" from the "metadata". Now repeat the process to get "title" from "music". It looks like the object is inside an array though so `o["metadata"]["music"][0]` will get you access to the actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens` and `SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) for this purpose.  They both support [JsonPATH query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) including wildcards:

```
        var o = JToken.Parse(result);
        var musicInfo = o.SelectTokens("metadata.music[0]")
            .Select(t => new
            {
                SongTitle = (string)t.SelectToken("title"),
                AlbumName = (string)t.SelectToken("album.name"),
                Artists = t.SelectTokens("artists[*].name").Select(n => (string)n).ToArray()
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then

```
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(musicInfo, Formatting.Indented));
```

Prints

> ```
> {
>   "SongTitle": "Listen (From the Motion Picture \"Dreamgirls\")",
>   "AlbumName": "B'Day Deluxe Edition",
>   "Artists": [
>     "Beyoncé"
>   ]
> }
> ```

which is what you want.